# html download attribute not working in django

Tags: html, django

I want to download an image file from HTML inside my Django app this is my code in the template.

```
        {% for pic in pics %}
          <a href="{{ pic.image.url }}" download>
            <img src="{{ pic.image.url }}">
          </a>
        {% endfor %}
```

The images are rendered and everything else is working fine. When I click on the image, it opens in fullscreen instead of downloading. I am using chrome. What am I doing Wrong?